# Docker - Python Django error entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I follow a tutorial about DRF backend and Docker use for test api.
Link tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tujhGdn1EMI
They were fully setup docker-compose and dockerfile. I am following but got error "`exec /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory`" on docker desktop.

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  api:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: docker/docker_files/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: backend/docker/docker_files/Dockerfile_app
    platform: linux/amd64
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

File Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN set -e; \
    apt-get update ;\
    apt-get -y install netcat ;\
    apt-get -y install gettext ;

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

RUN set -e; \
    /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip ;\
    python -m pip install -r /code/requirements.txt ;\
    chmod +x /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh ;

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

File entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py test

exec "$@"
```

My struture folder
DRF_docker
|__server.py
|__venv
|__docker-compose.yml
|__backend
|__reuiqrements.txt
|__docker
|__docker_files
|__Dockerfile
|__entrypoints
|__entrypoint.sh

I tried remove #!/bin/sh and got error exec /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh: exec format error
I tried shorty path to /code/entrypoint.sh and still no such file or directory

Comment: The `app` container has a `platform:` override; do you need something similar for the `api` container as well?  Can you simplify the setup and make it more reproducible by removing the Compose `volumes:`, `command:` override, and moving the Dockerfiles into the top-level directories?  Especially the `volumes:` can result in overwriting the entrypoint script in the image with something different; your `RUN chmod` gets hidden by the bind mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing the ENTRYPOINT.
From:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

To:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-e", "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

There seems to be an issue when running the Dockerfile on Linux:
https://github.com/bobby-didcoding/drf_course/issues/4

Comment: If you're going to do this then using a [shell form `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) is probably clearer; `ENTRYPOINT /code/.../entrypoint.sh` without the JSON-array syntax.  Note that both forms will cause the `CMD` to be completely ignored.

Comment: Thank you to answer my problem. But when I use your suggest to add "bash" and "-e", I could access to entrypoint.sh file but it send me new problem ` Unknown command: 'makemigrations\r'`.
After several times fixed I solve problem `Unknown command 'makemigrations\r'` and can run image with `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]`